# Animate a view added via IWindowManager

Tags: android, xamarin.android

If I add a view via the interface IWindowManager it won't animate normally: buttons will stay pressed, edit texts will show their previous values even if they are rewritten, etc.

Do you have a way for the view to update itself?

Thanks in advance.

```
[Service()]
public class ExampleService: Service
{
    View mView;
    IWindowManager wm;
    WindowManagerLayoutParams p;
    Handler handler;
    Timer timer;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        this.mView = new View(this);
        this.mView = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null);
        this.mView.LayoutChange += mView_LayoutChange;
        p = new WindowManagerLayoutParams()
        {
            ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
        };
        wm = (IWindowManager)GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
        wm.AddView(mView, p);
    }
}
```

Once the new view added via IWindowManager is displayed everything is fine, but if you move something on it (click a button, write some text, etc.) it won't update as a normal activity would. Is there a property I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

Add two views to the WindowManager: a black onw with Fomat = Format.Opaque and the view you want with Format = Format.Transparent...